# Clear input file field when user uploads invalid file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkfile(sender) {
    var validExts = new Array(".jpg", ".png", ".gif");
    var fileExt = sender.value;
    fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
      alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
               validExts.toString() + " types.");
      return false;
    
    }
    else return true;
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="file" name="attachFile" id="file" onchange="checkfile(this);"  accept="image/*"  onBlur="return chechExtension();"  required >
```

I used below javascript code for validation of throwing error when user enters invalid file.

Its working as it throws error whenever user uploads files other than jpg,gif,png but it just throws error.& does'nt clear the input file field. so the invalid file is uploaded in Input File.

Whats should I do to clear the field after error id user uploads invalid file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById("file").value = ""` to reset the value of the input back to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can do the following thing:

```
    var $copy = $('#file');
    $('#file').remove();
    $('.wrapper').append($copy);//$('.wrapper') is the parent DOM element of input
```

OR 
you can put this 'input' element in a "form" element. Like this:

```
   <form id="myform"><input ....></form>

    document.getElementById("myform").reset(); //you can reset your input button in this way
```